# Lua -randomly select 3 numbers (out of 250) in every run/event, but excluding one

Tags: random, lua

I would like to get random 3 numbers (e.g. 3, 177, 244) from an array of 0 to 250 in every event, and excluding a pre-defined number between 0 and 250 (e.g 220).

For example,

1. In the 1st event (push button),
   I got 220 from another data set, so I need random numbers like a=3, b=177, c=244 (a, b, c should not be 220).
2. In the 2nd event (push button),
   I got 15 from another data set,, so I need random numbers like a=77, b=109, c=166 (a, b, c should not be 15)

**Do you have any good idea to implement this?**
Looking for a good mathematician! Cheers.

Based on @Evan Wrynn, I tried the following, but I need one more step to get random 3 numbers in a table, right. Basically I try to put all numbers in t. d is a variable I got from another source. The outcome should be t which contains 3 random numbers (i.e. t={4, 88, 221} (except 85 in this case)). Currently t seems to get duplicate numbers :(. Completely alternative idea is also welcome.

```
d = 85
dt = {}
t = {}
table.insert(dt,d)
while table.getn(t) < 3 do
  function GetMathRandomExclude(lowerbound,upperbound,exclude)
    local x = math.random(lowerbound,upperbound)
    for _,v in pairs(exclude) do
      if v == x then
        return GetMathRandomExclude(lowerbound,upperbound,exclude)
      else
        return table.insert(t,x)
      end
    end
  end
  GetMathRandomExclude(1,250,dt)
end
for i, v in ipairs(t) do
  print(i, v)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  function GetMathRandomExclude(lowerbound,upperbound,exclude)
    local x = math.random(lowerbound,upperbound)
    for _,v in pairs(exclude) do
      if v == x then
        return GetMathRandomExclude(lowerbound,upperbound,exclude)
      end
    end
            return x
  end


d = 62
dt = {}
t = {}
table.insert(dt,d)

while table.getn(t) < 3 do
local randomnum =  GetMathRandomExclude(1,250,dt)
  table.insert(t,randomnum)
  table.insert(dt,randomnum)
end
for i, v in ipairs(t) do
  print(i, v)
end
```

The first problem you had was the random function, it would check only the first number as you returned after the if statement. This is sorted by putting it at the end of the function.

you can remove table.insert(dt,randomnum) if you don't want the numbers picked not to be added to the exclusion

Comment: This is what I was looking for!  Thank you! Actually I found math.random not very flexible. I thought of a clever math operators to randomly generate several numbers excluding a number, but it's not that simple...

Comment: Another way would be a for loop between a range, add that to a table.
Then randomly pick an element from the table.
(remove number from said table after)

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetMathRandomExclude(lowerbound,upperbound,exclude)
  local x = math.random(lowerbound,upperbound)
  if x == exclude then
    return GetMathRandomExclude(lowerbound,upperbound,exclude)
  end
  return x
end
```

> print(GetMathRandomExclude(1,3,2)) -> (when called 10 times I got "3" 7 times and "1" 3 times.

If the number = the number to exclude it than recalls the function.
You can check with a table to make it have multiple exclusions.

EDIT:

```
function GetMathRandomExclude(lowerbound,upperbound,exclude)
  local x = math.random(lowerbound,upperbound)
  if type(exclude) == "table" then
    for _,v in pairs(exclude) do
      if v == x then
        return GetMathRandomExclude(lowerbound,upperbound,exclude)
      end
    end
  else
    if x == exclude then
      return GetMathRandomExclude(lowerbound,upperbound,exclude)
    end
  end
  return x
end
```

> print(GetMathRandomExclude(1,100,{85,62})) -> 40

GetMathRandomExclude(NUMBER lowerbound, NUMBER upperbound, NUMBER OR TABLE exclude)

Comment: Thank you for the help. Nice one, but it's not quite there yet. I added my customised code above which would clarify what I would like to achieve at the end. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

in answers above we roll random number, and if it should be excluded, we roll another random number until we get one that should not be excluded. Drawback is if size of "ok" set and "exclude" set are comparable, we may reroll often.

i propose another approach, which i'll describe in example: we want random from 1 to 10 excluding 5. So we roll random from 1 to 9, and if our result is >4 then we add 1 to result. So we get random from 1 to 10 excluding 5. It can be implemented in following way:

```
local function get_random_n(min, max , exclude, n)
  local result = {}
  for i = 1, n do
    table.sort(exclude)
    result[i] = math.random(min, max - #exclude)
    for j = 1, #exclude do
      if result[i] > (exclude[j]-1) then
        result[i]=result[i]+1
      end
    end
    exclude[#exclude+1]=result[i]
  end
  return result
end

local function test()
  for j = 1, 10 do
    local x = get_random_n(1, 10, {3,5,7}, 7)
    print("========")
    for k = 1, #x do
      print(x[k])
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do I understand right that I can specify a range (min, max),  excluding numbers within the range (any length of an array), and n (the number of results in an array)? This looks more generic and wonderful. Thanks a lot! I guess the "test" function is not needed, and "get_random_n" is enough to execute.

Comment: yes, you understand it right. Test is just to demonstrate it works. every generated number is added to "exclude". But to work correctly number_to_generate must be <= size_of_range - size_of_exclude